# Create element function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, element

I am new in Javascript, So I have small problem, 
First here is my [live Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPRGqe) & written here.

this is my index.php file

```
<ul id="friends">
<li id="Maxi" class="user">Maxi</li>
<li id="John" class="user">John</li>
<li id="Henry" class="user">Henry</li>
<li id="Max"  class="user">Max</li>
<li id="Simon" class="user">Simon</li>
</ul>
<div id="windows"></div>
```

It is my stylesheet page.

```
.user{
text-align:center;
width:50px;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#9B59B6;
margin:5px;
border:4px solid #3498DB;
color:#F1C40F;
cursor:pointer;
float:right;
}
.mwindow{
width:150px;
height:200px;
border:2px solid #16a085;
}
.mwindow{
width:140px;
height:25px;
background-color:#1abc9c;
padding:5px;
}
.cls{
display:inline-block;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

And it is my js page

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('.user').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $html = '<div class="mwindow"><div class="hwindow">'+id+'<span class="cls">x</span></div></div>';
    $('#windows').append($html);

});

});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#friends').on('click','.user', function(){
    $('.mwindow').hide();
    });
  });
```

So my problem is when I click on one of users then display is showing none instead of display block.

Comment: I don't understand expected behaviour. Because if you want to show it, why are you hiding it: `$('.mwindow').hide();`???

Comment: `$('.mwindow').hide();` hides all elements with that class. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: $('.mwindow').hide();  this  should  work when i click  on .mwindow

Comment: `$('.mwindow').hide(); this should work when i click on .mwindow` BUT you are binding it on `.user` click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have this line `$('.mwindow').hide();`, which hides the elements that you append to `#windows`. To hide the element when you press on `x` you should attach the event on `.cls` and to `hide` the parent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#windows').on('click','.cls', function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.frnd').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $html = '<div class="mwindow"><div class="hwindow">'+id+'<span class="cls">x</span></div></div>';
    $('#windows').append($html);
 
});

});
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#windows').on('click','.cls', function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().hide();
 });
});
```

```css
body{
margin:0;
background-color:#999;
height:700px;
}
.frnd{
text-align:center;
width:50px;
height:20px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#9B59B6;
margin:5px;
border:4px solid #3498DB;
color:#F1C40F;
cursor:pointer;
float:right;
}
.mwindow{
width:150px;
height:200px;
border:2px solid #16a085;
}
.mwindow{
width:140px;
height:25px;
background-color:#1abc9c;
padding:5px;
}
.cls{
display:inline-block;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="friends">
    <li id="Maxi" class="frnd">Maxi</li>
    <li id="John" class="frnd">John</li>
    <li id="Henry" class="frnd">Henry</li>
    <li id="Max"  class="frnd">Max</li>
    <li id="Simon" class="frnd">Simon</li>
</ul>
<div id="windows"></div>
```

Comment: when i click on x then it mwindow should be hide

Comment: why  $(this).parent().parent().hide(); ?  i didnt understand it.

Comment: @Aryan because `.cls` (`$(this)`) have the parent `.hwindow` (`$(this).parent()`) and this have the parent `.mwindow` (`$(this).parent().parent()`), and you want to hide `.mwindow` that contains the `x` you clicked.